# Call v-on after focus changes

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I have a combo and a button

```
      <v-combobox
        :rules="someRule">
      </v-combobox>

      <v-btn
        v-on:click="onPressMethod">
        <span>click me</span>
      </v-btn>
```

Combo stores it's old value while it is focused

If i type something in combo and press button while combo is active, onPressMethod is called **before focus changes** so rule doesn't work, combo has old information and validation works wrong. Combo is actually empty, but view thinks it has old value. How can I make onPressMethod be called after focus changes? I tried v-on:keyup and I tried to force changing focus for combo, it didn't work.

Comment: Thought about `v-on:focus` and/or `v-on:blur` ?

Comment: v-on:focus for button doesn't work (combo still is not updating before button method is called)

Comment: Before click happens keydown. Try that instead of keyup.

Comment: If keydown works even earlier than click, is it solution? I need something that starts later, after focus changes, after combo validation occurs

Comment: Sorry i meant `mousedown` -> `mouseup`. After combo validation occurs, i would suggest to watch for `change` at `v-combobox`.

Comment: Mouseup didn't work, but I certainly will try listening. It didn't work properly last time I tried it, but I will make a research. Anyway I will tell the result:) Thank you